# How to mux 3 (high power) power supplies into 3 power rails with some pretty complex logic

Tags: power-supply, power, multiplexer, drone

I just want to say that this may be a bit of overkill but I'm really curious how I'd go about doing this.

I'm building a little drone from the ground up and got stuck on this issue.

I have 3 possible power sources, EXT (coming from an external power supply, probably 12V but not relevant), VBUS (coming from USB and mostly used for development, not enough power for motors) and BAT (an on-board battery, probably 4S but also not relevant).

There are 3 power rails: VCC which powers all of the control electronics, max ~35W, VMOT which powers the motors, possibly more than few hundred W and 5V which is usually generated by an SMPS using VCC rail but that's not needed when VBUS is present because it is already 5V so I would also like to bypass that.

I would want to make this system as flexible as possible so I cannot simply rely on some voltages being higher than others or something like that.

I really tried my best to come up with a concise way of explaining this logic but this "pseudocode" is the best I could do, I hope it's understandable and makes sense:

```
if (EXT is present) {
  VCC = EXT

  if (switch is on) {
    VMOT = BAT
  } else {
    VMOT = EXT
  }
}
else if (VBUS is present) {
  VCC  = nothing
  VMOT = BAT
  5V   = VBUS
}
else { // only BAT present
  VCC  = BAT
  VMOT = BAT
}
```

`switch` is just an arbitrary switch on-board so I can choose which PSU powers the motors because the external one might not be enough etc., just a flexibility thing.

Comment: Have you considered just using two relays, one with its coil powered by EXT and the other with its coil powered by VBUS? Where does 5V come from if VBUS is **not** present?

Comment: _"switch is just an arbitrary switch on-board"_ is this a physical switch, or an output from the flight controller?

Comment: There are ICs called power path controllers that do this function. Linear Tech is a good source.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I have thought about using relays but didn't really look into it yet. 5V is generated from either BAT or EXT when VBUS is not present using an SMPS.

Comment: @BruceAbbott It would probably just be a physical switch probably but I don't think it really matters, just some kind of a logic high/low.

Comment: @EE_socal I have looked into AD/LT PowerPath but implementing this logic using them doesn't seem too trivial.